# style.display="none" works in else{} but not in if{}

Tags: javascript, html

JS:

```
 function ToggleShow(lang_option){
   var elements = document.getElementsByClassName(lang_option);
   var langs = document.getElementsByClassName("lang");
   for(var i=0,l=elements.length;i<l;i++){
     if(elements[i] in langs){
       elements[i].style.display="block";
     }else{
       elements[i].style.display="none";
    }
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="button" aria-pressed="false" autocomplete="off" onclick="ToggleShow('lang-compiled')">
  Compiled
</button>
<div class="lang lang-interpreted">Python 3</div>
<div class="lang lang-compiled">C</div>
```

works, but if I reverse the two display functions (change `elements[i].style.display="block";` to `elements[i].style.display="none";` and vice versa), the buttons stop functioning without any errors in console.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Do you want "C" to toggle on/off?

Comment: It should toggle "Python" (as it isn't a compiled language). Currently it hides "C", which is why I need to change `display="block"` to `display="none"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`if(elements[i] in langs){` tests if the element in question is a *property* of the `langs` HTMLCollection, which is of course always false. If you wanted to check if the element *is included* in the HTMLCollection, you might turn the HTMLCollection into an array and use `.includes`:

```
 function ToggleShow(lang_option) {
   var elements = document.getElementsByClassName(lang_option);
   var langs = [...document.getElementsByClassName("lang")];
   for (var i = 0, l = elements.length; i < l; i++) {
     if (langs.includes(elements[i])) {
       elements[i].style.display = "block";
     } else {
       elements[i].style.display = "none";
     }
   }
 }
```

Or, you might trim your function to something like this, to keep your code DRY:

```
 function ToggleShow(lang_option) {
   var langs = [...document.getElementsByClassName("lang")];
   document.querySelectorAll('.' + lang_option).forEach(element => {
     element.style.display = langs.includes(element)
     ? 'block'
     : 'none';
   });
 }
```

Comment: Thanks! I added a section to effectively make all elements that don't contain lang_option hidden (as included in my post update). I think using "in" in the context I did is more of a Python thing and I assumed it worked both ways.

Answer (score 1):

> we use `in` to check a property in an object, not a value. Just need to change the expression of `if` block to make the code work...

```
function ToggleShow(lang_option) {
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName(lang_option);
  var langs = document.getElementsByClassName("lang");
  for(var i=0,l=elements.length;i<l;i++) {
    elements[i].style.display= langs.includes(elements[i]) ? "block" : "none";
    }
 }
```